# Limit disk usage on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Sorry if this is a simple question - I'm new to ELK and have it all running with data coming through ok.  My issue is that I'm concerned about storage growth given the number of records that will be coming through.

Having a search on the google I've seen that on GrayLog there is a setting to limit the amount of data to retain ( [Graylog2- how to config logs retention to 1 week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37313445/graylog2-how-to-config-logs-retention-to-1-week) ) and I'd like to do the same in ELK but I can't find the correct setting.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in GUI (yet). What you need is the [Curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/index.html) that can delete or rollup indices based on time (delete indices older than 7 days) or amount of documents in an index.

In a future Version there will be an [inbuilt tool](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x//index-lifecycle-management.html) for that in Kibana, but it´s not in the current release (6.5). It will probably release with Elastic 6.6 (as a beta), but you may even have to wait for 7.X

Answer (score 0):

They did indeed provide in-built tools! Elasticsearch 7.x and 8.x include index lifecycle management (ILM) policies to create rollover and deletion automation policies for your indexes.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html